# How to send "{}" in SendKeys

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to send "{" and "}" using `SendKeys.Send()`

I already tried to use `string.Replace{"{", "{{}"}`

```cs
txt = txt.Replace("{", "{{}");
txt = txt.Replace("}", "{}}");
SendKeys.Send(txt);
```

I expected it to send "{" and "}" but the Program throws an error

> System.FormatException

Comment: im not folowing do you want to send the letters a,n,d?

Comment: *"but the Program crashes"* - can you provide more details? What exception, call stack, etc.

Comment: Note that the second `Replace` will replace braces introduced with the first one. So "{" is first replaced by "{{}" and then the closing brace is replaced again yielding"{{{}}".

Comment: Where does `txt` come from? Can you add the escaped forms when `txt` is being created?

Comment: Why do you want to send the keys `{` or `}` ? What is the supposed destination? Might be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @AndrewMorton the text comes from a textbox the user can put text in

Comment: @PikaFan123 Will the user be deliberately using things like "{TAB}", or are the braces simple literals?

Comment: @RufusL, the question marked as duplicate does not escape braces but instead replaces tags enclosed in braces.

Comment: @PikaFan123 - you managed to get a good response with this question! Well done and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @AndrewMorton its just for text, no stuff like "{TAB}"

Comment: @PikaFan123 OK, in that case the [answer by A. Chiesa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54348883/1115360) looks to be the neatest one so far.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - out of interest... why do you say `StringBuilder` solution is the neatest? I prefer `Regex.Replace(txt, @"[/{/}]", m => string.Format("{{{0}}}", m.Value))`, it is a one liner and you can easily change the pattern if needed...

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia Both have their merits. I only said "looks to be", not "is". As a beginner, which would you find easiest to understand and modify?

Comment: @AndrewMorton As a beginner i find A Chiesas answer simpler to understand, i havent tried it yet, since im not at my pc atm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite clearly documented on the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Here the relevant bit:

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and
>   parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of
>   these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to
>   specify the plus sign, use "{+}". **To specify brace characters, use
>   "{{}" and "{}}"**. Brackets ([ ]) have no special meaning to SendKeys,
>   but you must enclose them in braces.

The problem with your solution is that you make 2 separate replacements.

Take the input string "{".

```
txt = txt.Replace("{", "{{}"); // input becomes "{{}"
txt = txt.Replace("}", "{}}"); // input becomes "{{{}}"
SendKeys.Send(txt);            // error!
```

I'm pretty sure there is some solution more elegant than this, but you could try something like:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(txt.Length);
for(var i = 0; i < txt.Length; i++)
{
    var c = txt[i];
    switch (c)
    {
      case '+':
      case '^':
      case '%':
      case '~':
      case '(':
      case ')':
      case '[':
      case ']':
      case '{':
      case '}':
        sb.Append('{');
        sb.Append(c);
        sb.Append('}');
        break;
      default:
        sb.Append(c);
        break;
    }
}
SendKeys.Send(sb.ToString());
```

**Edit** extended the escaping with a switch and a for to account for the other escapable chars.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia I updated the code snippet to account for the other chars.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out your second `Replace`, replaces the curly braces added by your first `Replace`.

To escape the curly braces within a string you could use `Regex` like this:
`SendKeys.Send(Regex.Replace(txt, @"[/{/}]", m => string.Format("{{{0}}}", m.Value)));`

Or even better escape all characters that have special meaning in this context ie. `Regex.Replace(txt, @"[/{/}/+/%/~/(/)]", m => string.Format("{{{0}}}", m.Value))`

Another completely different option would be to send characters one at the time and escape curly braces when necessary:

```
"some{}text".ToCharArray().ToList()
   .ForEach(a=> SendKeys.Send(a == '}' || a == '{' ? "{"+a+"}": a.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using a different variable to hold the entire string:

```
var txt = "asdf{}Asdf";
            var newString = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < txt.Length; i++)
            {
                if (txt[i] == '{')
                    newString.Append("{{}");
                else if(txt[i] == '}')
                    newString.Append("{}}");
                else
                    newString.Append(txt[i]);
            } 
            SendKeys.Send(newString.ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

`{` has to be escaped by `{{}`. `}` has to be escaped by `{}}`. This attempt to escape ...

```
// NON-WORKING EXAMPLE!
txt = txt.Replace("{", "{{}");
txt = txt.Replace("}", "{}}");
```

... has the problem, that right braces introduced by the first Replace are escaped again by the second replace. So starting from `{` you get

```
{  -->  {{}  -->  {{{}}
```

which is wrong. To avoid escaping braces introduced precisely as escapes, use a surrogate character for the closing escape brace in the first Replace. E.g. some Chinese character `閉`, assuming that you will never want to send this character.

```
txt = txt.Replace("{", "{{閉");
txt = txt.Replace("}", "{}}");
// After having done the escape, replace the surrogate by the closing brace again.
txt = txt.Replace("閉", "}");
```

If it is not sure whether a single character will never be sent, use a improbable character sequence as surrogate, possibly from different alphabets like `閉©ξ` (Chinese, Latin punctuation, Greek).

Comment: Not my downvote, but this is making assumption that the user won't enter `閉` (yes it is possible, have you ever trusted an user input?). All 3 others answers give better results

Comment: This really depends on the application. I have made applications that are localized to exactly 4 western European languages. Chinese will never be used in this application. But if a single surrogate is not safe enough, replace it by a sequence of characters as in [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).